# Issues with QGIS map projection and symbolizing point data

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, data, mapping

First off, I am using version 3.28 QGIS-LR on a Macbook 2015. I am currently taking an introduction course to GIS. One of the assignments was learning to project maps and visualize point data using data that looks at the total release of toxins in NJ. I first started by uploading the county boundaries of NJ (shapefile). Then I uploaded the toxic release data file (layer tab, add delimited text layer). The correct Geometry CRS is EPSG: 4269 – NAD83.

I customized the map and data points according to the instructions. As soon as I begin to work in the New Print Layout tab, something occurs where I either lose the data points or the county boundaries disappear. Eventually, it affects the project window as well. I have attached photos.

How can I fix this problem?

This is what my map looks like:

[image: The county boundaries disappear]

Below is what the final map should look like:
[image: What it should look like]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. More information about the nature of the layer not rendering should be provided.

Comment: Can you click on the map body and take a screenshot of the properties?